# Visual Studio 2019/2022 Blank Solution template is not available, cannot be found via search, and is not visible. How can I create a blank solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for a C# bootcamp. The tutor can create a blank solution with some steps but When I apply the same steps, I can not see Blank Solution. How Can I create a Blank Solution?

Any Help?

[image: Here is my visual studio screenshot]

[image: Image that shows my Visual Studio Tools 1]

[image: Image that shows my Visual Studio Tools 2]

Comment: Restarting can indeed solve many problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a bug about Visual Studio 2019. After 4 hours I restart my pc and reopen the Visual Studio for finding a solution. Despite I did not change anything, The Blank Solution part appears.

Answer (score 13):

We can use cli in this situation

The following example creates a .sln file in the current folder, with the same name as the folder:

`dotnet new sln`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

Comment: This is probably fine for a C# project, but likely isn't the best option for users hoping to use the solution for a different language/tool set.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of hassle and heartbreak and just use this/Artyom's solution.

Comment: @JoshuaK This just creates a blank .sln solution file, nothing to do with C#, or even specifically .NET. Once you have the solution, you can add any project type you like into it.

Answer (score 6):

Just found [this comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/8261#issuecomment-1445032959) which resolved my problem with recent version of VS (17.5.0)

[image]

Comment: Plus one for @Keytrap, minus one for M$

Comment: That is for .NET Framework. Not the same as .NET. Framework is the much older .NET.

Comment: This is not specifically intended for applications based on the .Net Framework. A solution is not tied to any specific version of .net. If you open the file with a text editor you won't see anything related to .net framework or .net (core). I don't know why it's named .net framework though.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022, select "Other"...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me earlier on. If the blank solution option doesn't show or it says it cannot be found as a result of your search. Just close down Visual Studio and reopen it and should reappear.

Answer (score 1):

You mighy want to try this button. It worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's also a bug that persists to Visual Studio 2022. I too was unable to find a Blank Solution option in Visual Studio 2022.

**What finally worked for me:** I created a blank solution in a prior version (Visual Studio 2019 in my case) and opened it in Visual Studio 2022.

**Bonus Tip:** Save the newly opened solution in Visual Studio 2022 as a Project Template. Use your custom project template to create a new solution.

**Things I tried that didn't work:** Selecting "Other", clearing the search, scrolling through all of them, closing and re-opening Visual Studio, restarting the computer. I already had .NET Framework project and templates selected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search it the searcher's conclusion is not true just scroll you will find[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjwq2.png) it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).